# Manipulating the search path for include files

Tags: c, gcc, include

My development environment is such that I have `some_header.h` in `/usr/include` and in `/another/directory`.  `/another/directory` contains some header files I need to include in my program, but I want to use `some_header.h` from `/usr/include`.  When I use

```
 gcc ... -I/another/directory
```

gcc uses `/another/directory/some_header.h`.  If I use

```
 gcc ... -I/usr/include -I/another/directory
```

gcc does the same thing because it ignores `/usr/include` since it is part of the standard search path, but it gets searched after non standard directories included with `-I.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Killed my answer, I had it backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at `-nostdinc` ?

The manual says:

> -nostdinc
>              Do not search the standard system directories for header files.
>              Only the directories you have specified with -I options (and the
>              directory of the current file, if appropriate) are searched.

Of course that means that *you* will have to specify anything that normally goes on the standard search path that you *do* want...

Answer (score 9):

Use the **-iquote** switch:

Include the files that are in **another/directory** using quotes:

```
#include "another_file.h"
```

Then use

```
gcc -iquote /another/include ...
```

to add a search path for quoted include files.  This switch will add a directory that is searched for quoted include files after the current directory and before -I and system include paths.

Include your other include files using brackets (i.e. `#include <header.h>`).

See here for more information:
[Where are include files stored - Ubuntu Linux, GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217943/where-are-include-files-stored-ubuntu-linux-gcc/1217952#1217952)

Comment: This seemed so close to working, but it turns out that the files in /another/directory use #include<file.h> so they couldn't find their include files when I used -iquote.

Comment: Hmm, thats odd.  The preprocessor should still search for <file.h> in the -I and system include paths.  Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unsetting the system INCLUDE path environment variable?

Comment: Well, it's empty, but that doesn't matter.  gcc automatically looks in certain directories, irrespective of environment variables. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path