# Adding a path to the end of gcc search path

Tags: linux, gcc

I can see that adding a path to the gcc search path can be done by using the -I flag. However, when using -v I can see that the path is being searched first.

Is there anyway I can have the search path I added, searched at the very end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-idirafter` option allows you to specify an include directory for consideration only after all regular `-I` directories and the standard system directories.  This is documented here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation

> `-idirafter` *dir*
>
> Search *dir* for header files, but do it after all directories specified with `-I` and the standard system directories have been exhausted. *dir* is treated as a system include directory. If dir begins with `=`, then the `=` will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see `--sysroot` and `-isysroot`.

Comment: Ah,yes, the `-i*` explanations on that page are exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation here on SO: [Manipulating the search path for include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240761)  and also [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_24.html) which may help you.

All three methods from [above](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_24.html)  are mentioned in the linked SO post.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-idirafter` option to add a directory to the end of the include search path.