# Adding standard libraries to C++ eclipse project

Tags: c++, eclipse

A (very) newbie C++ question:
Is there a way to automatically add the standard libraries to a C++ eclipse project? I installed the CDT Main Features plugin.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by standard C++ libraries?

Comment: Eclipse CDT does not provide a compiler, do you have one installed?

Comment: @Snappy - They are part of the compiler, so you don't have to install them separately.

Comment: I did not install a compiler. How do I install one in eclipse?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CPP_Dev_eclipse_CDT.aspx

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217943) answers where the files are and how you can find the location.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Preview is also a free option - if you aren't specifically trying to use Eclipse. It has its own compiler, however it's known to have some non-standard behavior. Otherwise, MinGW or Cygwin(with GCC and G++ options checked) are great if you're wanting to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add paths to STL headers in [Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) in Project Properties. This would enough for Indexer to resolve STL symbols properly.

Comment: And don't forget to install a compiler, which would provide the actual STL header files :)

Comment: Where are they located by default in Linux? /usr/include did not help

Answer (score 0):

If you need a compiler, make sure you have a visual studio installed, or cygwin; 
If you install cygwin, be sure to install the gcc and g++ compiler options which are deselected by default.

Point eclipse to the installed files and you should be good to go.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning MinGW as well for those who don't want a giant emulation layer.