# what is default path for header file included in c program?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

see if i write in any c file like

```
#include "header.h"
```

then it will search this file in current directory

but when i write

```
#include <header.h>
```

then where it will go to find this file ?
what is defualt path for header file included  in c program?

see i have installed gstreamer in /usr/local but when i am including

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
```

i am geeting `fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory`

How can i remove this error?

Comment: You can see the answer [here].

[here]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217943/where-are-include-files-stored-ubuntu-linux-gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path searched depends on the implementation (and current configuration). The correct way to find the include path is to use `pkg-config`

```
pkg-config --cflags gstreamer
```

Comment: it shows this error  --> Package gstreamer was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gstreamer.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gstreamer' found

Comment: @Mr.32 Perhaps you need to specify a version. Or maybe `gstreamer` isn't correctly installed. Look in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `/usr/share/pkgconfig`.

Comment: @Mr.32: As cnicutar has pointed out you need to use pkg-config. For gstreamer it is not just gstreamer, it is gstreamer-<version>. As you have installed gstreamer in /usr/local check the output of `ls /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gstreamer*`, you should find a bunch of .pc files. Now try this: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` then `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-0.10` assuming you found `gstreamer-0.10.pc` in `ls` command.  Does that show any output?

Comment: in tcsh export is not there but i have solved problem by setting gstreamer path using "setenv"

Answer (score 21):

Try running `gcc -v -E -`.  When I do, part of the output is as follows:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

It's not an answer to the gstreamer question, but I hope this still helps!

Pulled from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-09/msg00204.html)

Answer (score 6):

The default paths are

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/include
```

If you use another path, you can add in your compile command with `-I` flag. In your case, assuming you have a `/usr/local/gst/include` directory, you may add `-I/usr/local/gst/include` and use `#include <whatever_you_need.h>`

Answer (score 4):

The default path for `<>` stuff is `/usr/include`, at least on Unix.

You can add as many default paths as you want with `-I /my/new/path` compiler option.

Answer (score 3):

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` --verbose
```

and then CTRL+C

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a short description what this command does and how it helps with the question.

Comment: I agree with @dakab, you should explain how this helps the OP

Answer (score 2):

you can find those files in:

```
/usr/include
```