# How to include «pty.h» Header File on Unix / Add «pty.h» to Standard library C / C++

Tags: c, unix, include, standard-library, pty

I would like to include `pty.h` which is not normally available on Unix (Not included in standard library). On the Internet, you can get the related header file content. So how do you add this header file to the standard library, so that it's possible doing: #include «pty.h», and not #include "pty.h"
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have that file copied to `usr/include` or `usr/local/include`.
If you run `gcc -v -E -` ( got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7834234/11923286)) you will get the following output

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-E' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

which also shows (in the end) some system folders in which it looks for header files.