# Why is there no cdirent or sys/cstat

Tags: c++, c, linux

I was writing a C++ code that iterates through all the entries of a directory and decided to use [dirent.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html). Since I was using C++, I decided to use the C++ standard for including C library files [i.e. prefixing the library name with c and removing the .h at the end]

Without adding any functionality I decided to compile my program once to see if there was actually a `cdirent` or `sys/cstat`. g++ threw an error telling me that these files where not present

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cdirent>
#include <sys/cstat>
#include <sys/ctypes>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

}

dummy.cpp:2:19: error: cdirent: No such file or directory
dummy.cpp:3:21: error: sys/cstat: No such file or directory
dummy.cpp:4:22: error: sys/ctypes: No such file or directory
```

Following the advice given in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217943/where-are-include-files-stored-ubuntu-linux-gcc) on where to look for standard C++ header files I could locate `cstdio`, `cstdlib`, `ctime` and the like which brings me to my questions

1. When is a C standard library file converted to a C++ standard library file?
2. How should one include such files in the program? The [page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-system.html) here only talks about standard and non standard header files. But I believe `dirent.h` is a standard library file [Correct me if I am wrong]

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions

Comment: Instead of the Posix files, use Boost filesystem. Boost filesystem was slated for inclusion in the standard library in C++14 (the current standard), but as I recall it wasn't added. It will surely be there in C++17, then with the sillybugs hopefully removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dirent.h` and `sys/stat.h` are POSIX/SUS headers rather than standard C/C++ headers, and as such do not adhere to the standard C++ rules.

Comment: They pre-date the C++ standard by a decade and more, too.  As to why POSIX hasn't defined a C++ interface, that's a harder question to answer.  Maybe Boost should be encouraged to do it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Boost already has a filesystem sub-library.

Comment: How to include them? Do I need to wrap them with `extern "C"` or something?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev No. By the way you have the filesystem library in C++17 and later.