# Where to find #include<linux/xxxxx> header files under my MAC

Tags: macos, header, include, inotify

I'm using mac，I was trying to use inofity and fanotify so I have to

```
#include <linux/inotify.h>
```

But I didn't find a directory named "linux" under /usr/include.

Where can I find it?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217943/where-are-include-files-stored-ubuntu-linux-gcc

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm using MAC, not linux.

Comment: /usr/local/include?

Comment: Well, it doesn't include <linux> folder. I just wish to know if MAC has anything equivalent to linux's inotify or fanotify? I suppose there programmming api should be similar. Thanks.

Comment: OS X has `FSEvents`. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html

Comment: Thanks to Barmar's answer, it's to the point

Answer (score 1):

Header files in this directory are operating system dependent header files and they are just in Linux. You should search for equivalent of each header file with the same functionalities in other header files and their implementations are not the same.

For example, OS X handles file system change events with an event stream that have completely different implementation compare to iNotify of Linux.