# Installing linux library in C

Tags: c, linux

I am a beginner with `linux` and `C` and wanted to learn how to successfully install external libraries.

Therefore, I have a recent project to aid my understanding of my MacOS usb ports, I am taking steps into: [The Linux-USB Host Side API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/driver-api/usb/usb.html#introduction-to-usb-on-linux). This mentions the package is the the following:

```
<linux/usb/ch9.h>
```

I found this on the `linux` github: [linux-usb](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/usb/ch9.h).

How do I successfully install this onto my MacOS to use within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: What you linked to is the Linux kernel github repository. That is not a libary and it most certainly won't work on macOS

Comment: You will have a lot more luck doing your development on Linux.  This setup is particular to linux and will have no relevance on macOs

Comment: I'm afraid the linux headers are not compatible with Darwin, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41326848/1606345

Comment: @DavidRanieri This is all new to me and it makes sense. I instead did `brew install libusb` which seems to be the one for MacOS. However, It is not within the `usr/include` path, instead its within `/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.26`, any suggestions as to how I can access this>

Comment: After restarting my MacOS and entering into the console `brew unlink libusb && brew link libusb` it worked