# Printing usb devices gives Undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: c, linux, libusb

As with my previous post: [Installing linux library in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131054/installing-linux-library-in-c) after having managed to successfully install the library for my project. I have been following some example code and cannot manage to get it to work.

For example, I get multiple errors regarding the print statements (fixed from comments) -- how to successfully print out current devices access usb ports? -- It raises an issue with undefined symbols?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
libusb_device **list;
libusb_device *found = NULL;
ssize_t cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &list);
ssize_t i = 0;
int err = 0;
if (cnt < 0)
    perror("Some Error");
    exit(1);
 
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    libusb_device *device = list[i];
    if (device) {
        found = device;
        break;}}
 
if (found) {
    libusb_device_handle *handle;
    err = libusb_open(found, &handle);
    if (err)
        perror("Another Error");
        exit(1);
        }
 
libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);

return 0;
}
```

The errors I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libusb_get_device_list", referenced from:
      _main in exercise_1-eebbd8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Don’t just say you got an error.  **Show us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Comment: Also, note that `printf` is a formatted print. The first argument is a format string that defines how the rest of its arguments will be printed.

Comment: Single quotes and double quotes are two very different things in C.

Answer (score -2):

Your big problem is that you're not quoting your strings correctly.

```
perror('Some Error');
```

should be

```
perror("Some Error");
```

In C, single quotes are only used for individual characters. Strings have to be double-quoted.

It looks like your other errors are because you aren't including any header files that give declarations of the functions you want to use.

At the very least you need

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

but there are others you will need, like whatever library need has the definitions of the libusb functions.

Comment: Hi I have implemented these and updated the script after making amendments to the print statements based on the comments. Looks like a local error this time